# How to upload Mltipart file in Postman with JSON data object

Tags: json, file, postman

I am not getting how to Set JSON data object along with file upload

```
default ResponseEntity<FileUpload> updateFileInfo(@ApiParam(value = "Unique Identifier of the File",required=true) @PathVariable("fileId") UUID fileId,
        @ApiParam(value = "") @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file,
        @ApiParam(value = "") @RequestParam(value = "metadata", required = false) FileUpload metadata) {
    if(getObjectMapper().isPresent() && getAcceptHeader().isPresent()) {
    } else {
        log.warn("ObjectMapper or HttpServletRequest not configured in default FilesApi interface so no example is generated");
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
```

I need FileUplod object's JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can send the uploaded file as base64String through a JSON object.